# kernel Debug a process as soon as it starts with WinDbg

Tags: debugging, windows-10, windbg

I am trying to break on chrome.exe as soon as it is created. However, when debugging a Windows 10 machine using the lines below doesn't do anything, although with Windows 7 it works successfully.

```
!gflag +ksl
sxe ld chrome.exe
```

Is there something different I need to do for Windows 10 or something I have typed wrong?

EDIT: I have read that this does not work on Windows 10... but I have not found a solution.

Comment: It might not be convenent, but you could use the [Registry settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204634(v=vs.85).aspx) for the user mode debugger. This will make the application stop at the initial breakpoint. You can then attach the kernel debugger and detach (`qd`) the user mode debugger. (I'm not very familiar with kernel debugging)

Comment: I have *not* read that this doesn't work on Windows 10 and I verified that it does in fact work on my Windows 10. Does not reproduce.

Comment: I have managed to repro it on 3 different set ups now, so we must be doing something different.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us exactly what did you do. Perhaps you changes some configuration. Perhaps you got your Windows ISO from some malicious Russians site instead of from MSDN. There's really no way for us to know what you did without you telling us. You still didn't tell us where you read that story about `sxe ld` for user modules not working on Windows 10. Heck, you didn't even bother to mention bitness (not to mention build). If you don't want to tell us that's certainly your right. But not only it makes it hard to impossible to help, it kind of demotivates us from even trying.

Comment: @conio: oh dear... so many mistakes. Deleted my comment. Thanks for informing me.